# Derive t-test for slope (simple regression)

Tags: regression, self-study, hypothesis-testing, t-test, regression-coefficients

I'm using the Generalized likelihood ratio test in order to get the t test for slope, i.e.,

$H_{0}:\beta_{1}=b_{1}$ vs $H_{1}:\beta_{1}\neq b_{1}$

If $b_{1}=0$, we have that ${\sigma}_{MV|H_{0}}^{2}=\sum{{(Y-\overline{Y})}^{2}}$ and using the Generalized likelihood ratio test, we can use sum of squares and  these facts:

SST=SSE+SSR, and $\sum{{(\hat{Y}-\overline{Y})}^{2}}=\hat{\beta_{1}^{2}}{S}_{XX}$

But can you give me a hint for $b_{1}\neq 0$? Is not so clear for me

Comment: There is a lot of notation in your question that you don't define. Could you edit to add some context?